# insertcell() with unique ID

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with the insertRow & insertcell(), i have been searching around for the past few hours, but unfortunately, i have not found the answer.

I have a code which adds a new row to my table with 5 cells.

```
function myCreateFunction() {

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"des\" name=\"des\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"qu\" name=\"qu\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"pu\" name=\"pu\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell4.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"rl\" name=\"rl\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"tlht\" name=\"tlht\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";

return false;
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);

return false
}
```

Each time i hit the button,

```
onclick="return myCreateFunction()"
```

A new row is added, but the issue is, if i add 2 rows each 5 cells will have the same ID & NAME. Each cell1 will have same ID, each cell2 will have same ID.....

No need to say that this is used inside a form, where i will need to add a new row and add content, which will be saved in a database.

WHat i need ? i need to add a number next to the NAME and ID each time i create a new row.

Example of what i need:

if i hit the button it will create all 5 new cells BUT the ID & NAME changes. Here and now, the name and id of the first cell is "des" when button click i need des1, when i click again i new row is created but the cell name and id is des2.. des3... des4... the number should be applied to all id's and name's of all cells created on the OnClick.

Don't know if it's clear enough.

Thank you very much, help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple options here:
keep a tracking list of every time the function is called

```
var index = 0;

function myCreateFunction() {
   ....your function.....
   cell.id = "des" + index;
   index++;
}

generate a unique id every time
function newGuid()
{
    //Generates a guid.
    var returnGuid = "";
    var hexChar = "abcdef1234567890";

    for (var i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
    {
        returnGuid += hexChar.charAt(Math.random()*16);
        if(i == 7 || i == 11 || i == 15 || i == 19)
        {
            returnGuid += "-";
        }

    }
    return returnGuid.toString();
}

"... id=\"des\" " + newGuid()
```

Comment: Which issues do you run into?

Comment: I am having some issues with the code:

THe page refreshes and than nothing happens, i do not have enough room inside the comment to show you, i will answer my question for more typing space...

Answer (score 0):

Make a global variable like count and use it to create the id.

NOTE: Check than you can use `'` instead of `\"` inside a string to clarify:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='des" + count + "' name='des' placeholder='' class='form-control input-sm' value=''/>";
```

PS: at the end of adding a line remember to increase count and reset it if necessary

```
count = count + 1
```

Comment: Can't seem to understand how to implement your code. Sorry but my understanding of javascript is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

This is the original code working while adding a new line, this is where the ID of the input line should be increased with a number each time i hit the button ADD LINE (or in french AJOUTER)

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="portlet box red ">
                            <div class="portlet-title">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Devis
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portlet-body form">
                                    <table id="myTable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="40%"><center><b>Description</b></center></td>
                                        <td width="10%"><center><b>Quantité</b></center></td>
                                        <td width="20%"><center><b>Prix U HT</b></center></td>
                                        <td width="10%"><center><b>Remise %</b></center></td>
                                        <td width="20%"><center><b>Total</b></center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="40%"><input type="text" id="des" name="des" placeholder="" class="form-control input-sm" value="<? echo $_POST['des']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td width="10%"><input type="text" id="qu" name="qu" placeholder="" class="form-control input-sm" value="<? echo $_POST['qu']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td width="20%"><input type="text" id="pu" name="pu" placeholder="" class="form-control input-sm" value="<? echo $_POST['pu']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td width="10%"><input type="text" id="rl" name="rl" placeholder="" class="form-control input-sm" value="<? echo $_POST['rl']; ?>"/></td>
                                        <td width="20%"><input type="text" id="tlht" name="tlht" placeholder="" class="form-control input-sm" value="<? echo $_POST['tlht']; ?>"/></td>
                                    </tr>                                       
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The JS code ading a line

```
<script>
function myCreateFunction() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"des\" name=\"des\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"qu\" name=\"qu\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"pu\" name=\"pu\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell4.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"rl\" name=\"rl\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"tlht\" name=\"tlht\" placeholder=\"\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" value=\"\"/>";

return false;
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);

return false
}
```